# Automation account rerun, a jobshedule already exist

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-automation

I have created a CD pipeline in Azure DevOps that will deploy an Azure Automation account and a runbook , shedule , jobshedule through ARM templates.

All working fine except when rerunning the template. My template is a part of a large deployment process that is still under construction so until the total scope is finished the ARM template that creates the runbook, shedule, jobshedule will rerun with every release.

The problem right now is the following: Whenever I rerun the template with a new release pipeline, I receive following error

> `A job schedule for the specified runbook and schedule already
>   exists.`

At first I tried to be smart so added a GUI before the name of my jobshedule but the shedule itself attaches the runbook with the shedule and the deployment was smart enough to figure it out that the shedule was already connected to the runbook. Is there a way of making this still within the DevOps mindset / process so that I can rerun my templates with no problem.

The workaround solution I have created atm is to delete the shedule at every deployment but that seems like a very bad workaround.

Comment: Related feature request from UserVoice / feedback forum is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/33065122-redeploying-jobschedule-resource-from-arm-template) that's currently in triaged state.

Comment: I can delete this SO question but it seems that maybe here is a good juming point to the feedback on azure for people who came across this online. So if you would like to put your comment in an answer that way I can accept your answer.

Comment: Agreed! Great thought that this update / answer would help people who come across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related feature request from UserVoice / feedback forum is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/33065122-redeploying-jobschedule-resource-from-arm-template) that's currently in triaged state.

Answer (score 0):

Job Schedule id need to be unique for each deployment as per azure documentation.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing a link to the documentation that states this.